# Controlling Request Timeout in Apache 4.x Client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

How do you set the timeout on the `HttpClientConnectionManager` to longer than 2 minutes?

We are connecting to a long running SOAP service which processes for a few (5-8) minutes before returning a HTTP response. We have no control over this service so we need to allow for long periods of activity before a response is received.

Using the Apache HttpClient 4.3.2 library we notice the Connection Manager appears to be closing the connection due to inactivity after 2 minutes:

```
16:14:45.805 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(124) - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /someendpoint.do?SOAP HTTP/1.1
16:14:45.805 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> content-type: application/soap+xml
16:14:45.805 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 536
16:14:45.806 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: someserver.com
16:14:45.806 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
16:14:45.806 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)
16:14:45.806 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
16:14:45.806 DEBUG o.a.h.headers.onRequestSubmitted(127) - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic Y290GARBAGE36Om9uZXR
16:16:46.750 DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.close(79) - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
16:16:46.750 DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.shutdown(87) - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
16:16:46.750 DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec.abortConnection(126) - Connection discarded
16:16:46.751 DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.close(79) - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
16:16:46.751 DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.releaseConnection(282) - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {tls}->http://http-proxy.mydomain.com:8080->https://someserver.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
16:16:46.753 INFO  o.a.h.i.e.RetryExec.execute(93) - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
16:16:46.758 DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.RetryExec.execute(98) - The target server failed to respond
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) ~[httpclient-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
```

We have tried `connMgr.closeIdleConnections( 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES );`, specifying our own `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy`, and setting timeouts in the request config:

```
config = RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
  .setSocketTimeout(soTimeout)
  .setConnectTimeout(connTimeout)
  .setConnectionRequestTimeout(rqTimeout)
  .build();
```

Are we missing some complementary settings such as setting a timeout *here* and also setting a flag *there* or that both *this* and *that* are set to the same value?

What is the proper way to prevent the connection from being closed when the server is not expected to respond for more than 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoHttpResponseException basically means the connection was terminated by the opposite endpoint (or an intermediary). Your timeout settings on the client side look perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks @oleg. We are in the process of confirming the proxy time-out although we have been told it is set to 5 minutes.